# How: Use cvCanny with ruby-opencv

Tags: ruby, opencv

I was wondering how to use cvCanny with ruby-opencv. I couldn't find any proper documentation.
That's what I have to far…

```
require "rubygems"
require "opencv"
include OpenCV

original_window = GUI::Window.new "original"
hough_window = GUI::Window.new "hough circles"

image = IplImage::load "stuff.jpg"
gray = image.canny(0.3, 0.8)

hough_window.show gray
GUI::wait_key
```

**Error:**

```
$ ruby houghcircle.rb
houghcircle.rb:11:in `canny': /Users/someuser/Development/Workspaces/2012/Libs/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/imgproc/src/canny.cpp:282: error: (-215) src.size == dst.size && src.depth() == CV_8U && dst.type() == CV_8U in function cvCanny (OpenCV::CvStsAssert)
    from houghcircle.rb:11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
error: (-215) src.size == dst.size && src.depth() == CV_8U && dst.type() == CV_8U in function cvCanny (OpenCV::CvStsAssert)
```

That's because you should convert image to grayscale (single-channel image) using `cvtColor` with parameter `CV_BGR2GRAY`. Canny can be applied only to such images.

Comment: any idea how to only detect "white" colored circles?

Comment: use color segmentation + houghCircles.

Comment: …it's hard to finde anything on this for ruby-opencv

Comment: How to translate this to ruby-opencv // cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(20, 100, 100), cvScalar(30, 255, 255), imgThreshed)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the solutions provided by @ArtemStorozhuk at stackoverflow.com and @ser1zw at github.com .
I have tried following solution at the environment of Ruby 2.3, opencv 2.4.13 and ruby-opencv 0.0.16 .

```
mat = OpenCV::CvMat.load("image.jpg") # load a image in 3ch    
gray = mat.BGR2GRAY  # same as cvCvtColor(mat, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY)
```

Reference:
1. Solution provided by @ArtemStorozhuk.
2. https://github.com/ruby-opencv/ruby-opencv/issues/9 provided by @ser1zw at github.com .